# How to update Teamscard with PowerAutomate

Tags: json, automation, microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I need help, this is a dynamic Teams Card. It can contain several test cases:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "size": "medium",
      "text": "TestGroup: 11 test case(s) - 4 failures - 63.64% success rate - 178.38099999999997sec total time",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "type": "TextBlock"
    },
    {
      "title": "Test1 failed after 10.402sec. Owner: xyz",
      "valueOff": "False",
      "valueOn": "True",
      "value": "false",
      "id": "Test1",
      "type": "Input.Toggle"
    },
    {
      "size": "small",
      "text": "Pipeline Url: xyz.de",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "type": "TextBlock"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "title": "Save",
      "type": "Action.Submit"
    }
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "msTeams": {
    "width": "full"
  }
}
```

Now I want to use PowerAutomate to create a flow that is triggered when "When someone responds to an adaptive card". It all works really well. You get the following response:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "teamsFlowRunContext": {
      "MessagePayload": {
        "Id": "1693912153540",
        "From": {
          "Application": null,
          "Conversation": null,
          "Device": null,
          "User": {
            "DisplayName": "test",
            "Id": "id"
          }
        },
        "Body": {
          "ContentType": null,
          "Content": null
        },
        "Subject": null,
        "LinkToMessage": "link",
        "ChannelData": null
      },
      "Id": null,
      "ChannelData": {
        "EventType": null,
        "InvalidateInvokeCache": null,
        "Team": null,
        "Tenant": {
          "Id": "tenantid"
        },
        "Channel": null,
        "Notification": null,
        "OnBehalfOf": null
      },
      "From": {
        "Id": "xyz",
        "Name": "Flow",
        "Role": null,
        "AadObjectId": null,
        "Properties": null
      },
      "Conversation": {
        "Id": "xyz",
        "Name": "NotificationTest",
        "IsGroup": true
      },
      "Locale": "de-DE",
      "CommandContext": null,
      "LocalTimezone": null
    },
    "cardOutputs": {
      "Test1": "false",
      "Test2": "True",
      "Test3": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

I then used Select to convert the cardOutputs to an array so that I can loop over them. But now I just don't understand how I can edit the JSON from the old message in such a way that the values ​​of the toggle.inputs are updated

I know how to send away the new Adaptive Card but not how to change it or rebuild it...
The bottom line is I have a loop that goes through the bodies, then one that goes through the card outputs, and then a condition that compares the ID to the key. If that fits, the value of the toggle.input should be replaced.

Is there perhaps a better solution, such as somehow simply getting the old message sent along in an edited version and then simply sending it back to teams?

Answer (score -1):

To update a Teams card with Power Automate, you can use the "Update Adaptive Card" action in Power Automate. This action allows you to modify the content of an existing Adaptive Card and send it back to Teams.

Here are the steps to update a Teams card with Power Automate:

- Create a new flow in Power Automate and choose the trigger that
  suits your scenario. For example, you can use the "When a new
  message is posted in a channel" trigger.
- Add an action to get the details of the Teams message. For example,
  you can use the "Get message details" action and provide the
  necessary inputs like the Team ID, Channel ID, and Message ID.
- Add an action to update the Adaptive Card. Search for the "Update
  Adaptive Card" action and select it.
- Configure the "Update Adaptive Card" action by providing the
  necessary inputs:

  ```
  Card ID: This is the ID of the Adaptive Card you want to update. You
  can find the Card ID in the message details obtained in the previous
  step.

  Card JSON: This is the updated JSON representation of the Adaptive
  Card. You can modify the card content using expressions or dynamic
  content from previous steps in the flow.
  ```
- Save the flow and test it by posting a new message in the specified
  Teams channel. The Adaptive Card in the message will be updated with
  the changes you made in the "Update Adaptive Card" action.

Note: The "Update Adaptive Card" action requires the "Microsoft Teams - Actionable Messages" connector to be added to your Power Automate environment. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to add connectors and use this action.

You can find more information about updating Teams cards with Power Automate in the [Microsoft Teams documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json#updating-cards).